Check if $\sigma(n) = \sum \limits_{d|n}d$ is surjective

Check if $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ where $\sigma(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n}d$ is surjective.

Hello! I've been struggling to come up with a proof for this problem.
We know that $\sigma(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{r}\frac{p_i^{a_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}$, for $n = p_1^{k_1} \cdot p_2^{k_2} \cdot ... \cdot p_r^{k_r}$,
where we can see that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists one $m\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $\sigma(n)=m$.
But how could I go about proving this for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$?
Any hints and guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

Have a look at $m=2$.

Thank you!!!!! It completely escaped me!!

The only function $f$ with $f(n)\geq n$ for all $n$ which is onto is $f(n)=n.$

Others missing: $5, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, \cdots$ with more in OEIS A007369 - in a sense, almost all integers are not a $\sigma(n)$
